# Is it possible to call Java methods (or invoke objects) using .NET on cross platform?

Tags: java, .net, cross-platform, hive

1) I have implemented a task in Hive (Hadoop).

2) Also there is some GUI which is in .NET. 
   My Task is from this GUI, I want to send all parameters to Hive (Ununtu) from GUI which is in 
   .NET and again from Hive to GUI for processed result.

My question is that Is it possible to call Java methods (or invoke objects) using .NET?
Because I am using VM (Ubuntu) for Hive and Hadoop which is in java. I am also dealing .NET which is in Windows.

I am also new to .NET

Pls suggest me some solution to me.

Comment: So you're basically describing a client (GUI on Windows) - server (Hadoop/Hive on Ubuntu) architecture, don't you? In this case have a look at language independent remoting options like CORBA or webservices.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, you may say it in a way. But in short whatever GUI part is on the side of windows and processing part is on linux (Hive, Hadoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cross-platform (and cross-language) communication there are a few options:

- [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) and [alternatives](http://linuxfinances.info/info/corbaalternatives.html)
- Webservices (e.g. using [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP))
- Restful services
- etc.

What you're using depends on your requirements (complexity, performance etc.) and what you already have available (I know neither Hadoop nor Hive that well, but I'd assume they already provide webservices or a REST interface).